# Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. android studio

Tags: java, android

I am getting an error when i try to run the app:

[image: the errors]

As you see it shows alot of stuff in this error With weird terms its something I never saw before.

This is my gradle.build(app) code I had modified it but then i reverted all the modifications:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.revapps.quranj30'
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.revapps.quranj30"
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }


}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

    implementation 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.0'


    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.7.0'
    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
}
```

I have tried to look at other peoples problem and what the answer to their problem was but Nothing answered my questions.

Its alot of errors and has a lot of terms i am unfamiliar with